# Android Studio - Tablet emulator not showing correct resolution

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adt, nexus-10

Just created a Nexus 10 emulator but when I start it, the wrong resolution is displayed. It keeps appearing as 800 x 1280 when it should be appearing as 2560 x 1600. Does anyone know what on earth is going on and how this can be fixed?

[image: wrong res]
[image: Correct res]
[image: wrong res in Nexus 10 emulator]

Comment: in last step, go to 'advanced settings' while creating AVD and select appropriate skin.

Comment: Oh OK cool. Working now. Cheers for that. Can you put what you said as an answer please.

Comment: ok...I'm putting answer

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As requested by OP,

In the last step while creating your AVD, go to **Advance Settings** and select appropriate **skin** (or preferably select '**No Skin**' option) to make sure your it comes with the resolution that you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good point. For some reasons, the skins installed with Android Studio seem to have wrong resolutions, even for Google's devices.

Comment: @JoseGómez update existing or install new version 1.1. It will work for you.

Comment: What is the appropriate skin? nexus_10 is already selected but it still has wrong resloution

Comment: @osrl then select 'NO SKIN' and try.

Comment: I cant change skin definition. It always go back to the previous configuration when i change it. Any ideas why?

Comment: @VictorAugusto did you click on that drop down?

Comment: @KrupalShah i definitely did :)

Comment: then that may be a bug in Android Studio that occurs in certain circumstances. You can file an issue on Google issue tracker.